# Playing audio & Video in a JFrame window

Tags: java, swing, audio, video, jmf

I am trying to add a video to a JFrame window but running into trouble.  I found some stuff online about JMF but I think that Javax right?  Can I use Javax and swing together?  Right now I have some code in there that is not working, one because I need a Player class (or is there a Player import I'm missing) and I'm not sure what needs to go in there, two because I think JMF might be Javax and I do not know if that and swing can be used together?

What I'm trying to do is when a button is pressed the JFrame window is cleared and a video pops up.  I've got to the place where I'm trying to add the video.  Is this difficult and a lot of code or something simple like adding a picture?  I would like to add an audio clip on the JFrame instead of the lengthy JLabel I have on there now.

**I put stars by the code in question.**

Any tips or pointer in the right direction is greatly appreciated!

```
public class MultiForm extends JFrame{

    private JComboBox menu;
    private JButton bluePill;
    private JButton redPill;
    private JLabel matrixQuote;
    private int matrixSelection;
    private JFrame newFrame;
    private JPanel panel;
    private JPanel panel2;
    private static String[] fileName = {"", "The Matrix", "Another Option"};


public MultiForm() {
    super("Multi Form Program");        
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    menu = new JComboBox(fileName);
    add(menu);

    TheHandler handler = new TheHandler();
    menu.addItemListener(handler);  

}

public void matrixPanel() {

    TheHandler handler = new TheHandler();
    //Create a new window when "The Matrix" is clicked in the JCB
    newFrame = new JFrame();
    panel = new JPanel();
    panel2 = new JPanel();

    newFrame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    newFrame.setSize(500, 300);
    newFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(newFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);      

    matrixQuote = new JLabel("<html>After this, there is no turning back. "
            + "<br>You take the blue pill—the story ends, you wake up "
            + "<br>in your bed and believe whatever you want to believe."
            + "<br>You take the red pill—you stay in Wonderland, and I show"
            + "<br>you how deep the rabbit hole goes. Remember: all I'm "
            + "<br>offering is the truth. Nothing more.</html>");

    panel.add(matrixQuote);
    newFrame.add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    //Blue pill button and picture. 
    Icon bp = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Blue Pill.png"));
    bluePill = new JButton("Blue Pill", bp);
    panel2.add(bluePill);   
    bluePill.addActionListener(handler);

    //Red pill button and picture
    Icon rp = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Red Pill.png"));
    redPill = new JButton("Red Pill", rp);
    panel2.add(redPill);

    newFrame.add(panel2, BorderLayout.CENTER);      
    newFrame.setVisible(true);
}

private class TheHandler implements ItemListener, ActionListener{

    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent IE) {
        //listen for an item to be selected.
        if(IE.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
            Object selection = menu.getSelectedItem();

            if("The Matrix".equals(selection)) {
                matrixPanel();
            }
            else if("Another Option".equals(selection)) {   
            }
        }   
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent AE) {
        if(AE.getSource() == bluePill) {
            newFrame.remove(panel);         
            newFrame.remove(panel2);
            newFrame.repaint();
*******************************************************************************         
            //TRYING TO ADD VIDEO TO THE NEWLY CLEARED JFRAME
            URL mediaURL = getClass().getResource("WAKE-UP.MP4");
            Player mediaPlayer = Manager.createRealizedPlayer(mediaURL);
            //get component for video and the playback controls...I think
            Component video = mediaPlayer.getVisualComponent();
            Component controls = mediaPlayer.getControlComponent();
            add(video, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            add(controls, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        }
    }   
}

//MAIN
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MultiForm go = new MultiForm();
    go.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    go.setSize(400, 200);
    go.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Comment: Since the JMF isn't really been maintained any more, I'd consider having a look at the VLC bindings (vlcj) or JavaFX's media support

Comment: *"JMF but I think that Javax right?"* - No, JMF pre-dates JavaFX ... by a lot

Comment: *"Can I use Javax and swing together?"* - Yes, see [JavaFX for Swing Developers](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/swing/jfxpub-swing.htm), [3 Integrating JavaFX into Swing Applications](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/swing-fx-interoperability.htm) and [JavaFX-Swing Interoperability](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/fx_swing.htm) for more details

Comment: Oh ok.  I'll check out VLCJ, is that something easy to code for something simple like this?

Comment: Video and Audio integration aren't what I'd call easy regardless of the API, they are going to some work and an understanding how how the particular API's work

Comment: Oh ok, I was hoping it would be something easy like adding a picture.  I'll figure it out, I'd like to learn how to do it.  Thanks again Mad!

Comment: What about embedding a youtube video onto the JFrame, is that something that's a little easier that you guys could help me out with?

Comment: No, I'd say that would actually be harder. I think VLC can do it, don't know about JavaFX's media support, but maybe it's WebView component might be able to do it